# Disable url editing in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, url-rewriting

I am very new to MVC . I have a address of view in my Addressbar as

`http://localhost:3436/User/View1` When I edit the word `View1` and add `View2`(Which is another view ) i am redirected to it..

I also noticed that such behaviour is working in Stack Overflow

How can I disable this behaviour in my **MVC 2** ?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to completely disallow GET requests manually formulated in the address bar of a browser.  Are you restricting access to the view based on user privileges?  If so, you should use the AuthorizeAttribute to prevent certain actions based on user authentication and authorization.  If you are trying to prevent the user from browsing manually rather than being restricted to links you provide, then you have limited options such as obfuscating the url, checking for empty referral url, requiring a POST token, etc.  This leads to poor usability and is not recommended.  Simple checks like referral URL are easily spoofed anyway.